# Weekly background code not working

Tags: theme-development, css, custom-background

I have this code I want to implement onto my website. I have successfully set up a child theme. This code is suppose to change the background every day of the week. I am not all too familiar with Wordpress, and I am wondering where I should place it and how. Can someone please give me step by step instruction what I need to do?

The code is below. Thank you very much.

---

```
function chgDailyImg()

{

var imagearray = new Array();

imagearray[0] = "sundaypic.jpg";

imagearray[1] = "mondaypic.jpg";

imagearray[2] = "tuesdaypic.jpg";

imagearray[3] = "wednesdaypic.jpg";

imagearray[4] = "thursdaypic.jpg";

imagearray[5] = "fridaypic.jpg";

imagearray[6] = "saturdaypic.jpg";



var d = new Date(); /*** create a date object for use ***/

var i = d.getDay(); /*** use the date object to get the day of the week - this will be a number from 0 to 6 - sunday=0, saturday=6 -it's the way counting works in javascript it starts at 0 like in the arrays ***/

document.getElementById("dailyImg").src = imagearray;

}/* CSS Document *//* CSS Document */
```

Comment: voting to reopen, as the question is trivial but on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, the tag that you want to call to execute your function is the [`wp_head()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

Looking at the code you provides, you have the idea down, but I decided to rewrite it differently. In your child theme's [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php) file, add the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_238911_weekly_background' );
    function wpse_238911_weekly_background() {
    $day = date( "l" );

    switch( $day ) {
        case 'Monday':
            $background_image = 'mon-img.jpg';
            break;
        case 'Tuesday':
            $background_image = 'tue-img.jpg';
            break;
        case 'Wednesday':
            $background_image = 'wed-img.jpg';
            break;
        case 'Thursday':
            $background_image = 'thu-img.jpg';
            break;
        case 'Friday':
            $background_image = 'fri-img.jpg';
            break;
        case 'Saturday':
            $background_image = 'sat-img.jpg';
            break;
        case 'Sunday':
        default:
            $background_image = 'sun-img.jpg';
            break;
    }

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url( 'http://web.site/img/<?php echo $background_image; ?>' );
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Just switch out the `mon-img.jpg` to your actual image names and change the `http://web.site/img/` path to wherever you will be having your day-of-the-week images stored.

Comment: Note that native PHP `date()` will always be in GMT in WP context, that can cause day  to be significantly off in timezones with considerable offsets. I would use something like `date_i18n( 'N' )` on top of my head (localized time, but numeric so that translation doesn't interfere).

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is JavaScript, and it should be placed within a JavaScript file inside of your child theme, e.g.:

`/your-child-theme/js/background-changer.js`

Your child theme should then enqueue your JS file from within its `functions.php` file, like so:

```
function wpse238911_load_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse238911_load_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/background-changer.js', array(), false, false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse238911_load_js' );
```

This is really the only WordPress specific part of your issue.

It looks like there may be a some problems with your JS too. You are assigning the entire `imagearray` to the `src` attribute of the `#dailyImg` element. It looks like you should be using `imagearray[i]`. Also `chgDailyImg()` is never executed. Here's a possibly helpful fixed version:

```
function chgDailyImg() {

    var imagearray = new Array();
    imagearray[0] = "sundaypic.jpg";
    imagearray[1] = "mondaypic.jpg";
    imagearray[2] = "tuesdaypic.jpg";
    imagearray[3] = "wednesdaypic.jpg";
    imagearray[4] = "thursdaypic.jpg";
    imagearray[5] = "fridaypic.jpg";
    imagearray[6] = "saturdaypic.jpg";

    var d = new Date(); /*** create a date object for use ***/
    var i = d.getDay(); /*** use the date object to get the day of the week - this will be a number from 0 to 6 - sunday=0, saturday=6 -it's the way counting works in javascript it starts at 0 like in the arrays ***/

    document.getElementById("dailyImg").src = imagearray[i];
}
chgDailyImg();
```

At this point we're talking about vanilla JavaScript, and that's off topic for this site. You might have better luck over on Stack Overflow for JavaScript questions.